# Нужно исправить проблему выполнения команды, а точнее ее ошибку: Application command 'imagine' not found

Tags: python, изображения, бот, discord.py, python-openai

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import openai  

# Your bot's token from the Discord Developer Portal
TOKEN = 'токен спрятан'

# Your OpenAI API key (if using OpenAI)
OPENAI_API_KEY = 'токен спрятан'

# Prefix for your bot commands
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)

# Event handler for when the bot is ready
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

# Define a command for generating images from text
@bot.command()
async def imagine(ctx, *, prompt):
    try:
        # Call the text-to-image generation API (replace with the actual API call)
        # Here we're using OpenAI GPT-3 as a placeholder (requires OpenAI's API)
        if OPENAI_API_KEY:
            openai.api_key = OPENAI_API_KEY
            response = openai.Completion.create(
                engine="davinci",  # Replace with the appropriate engine/model
                prompt=prompt,
                max_tokens=50,  # Adjust as needed
                n = 1
            )
            generated_image_text = response.choices[0].text.strip()
        else:
            generated_image_text = "Text-to-image API not configured."

        await ctx.send(generated_image_text)

    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f'Error: {str(e)}')

# Start the bot
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Перенесите заголовок в вопрос и приведите полный текст ошибки с трейсбэком.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете устаревшую версию (использование `@bot.command()` в оригинальной [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py)). Удалите `discord.py`, скачайте [pycord](/questions/tagged/pycord) (`pip install py-cord`). Код не меняйте, он будет работать и на `py-cord`е.

---

Если всё-таки будет выдавать ошибку - ещё раз скачайте `discord.py` (`pip install discord.py`)